# Run a .net program on a folder by right clicking and selecting program

Tags: c#, .net

I have a program that cleans up the names of files within a folder. It removes the spaces and illegal characters and replaces them.

This currently works by debugging the program in Visual Studio and finding the folder to run the clean up on using the `folderBrowser`. I think it would be really cool if I could just find the folder in my Documents without running Visual Studio that I want to clean up, and then right click and select the 'file clean up' program from the usual list (notepad, open, sent etc).

I am not asking anyone to build this for me, I just would like to be pointed in the right direction into how this could be done.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement windows shell extension ([sample](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/SimpleContextMenu.aspx))